# Laravel reuse session on subdomain

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-8, session-cookies

Let's say, I created 2 server and 4 sub domains.

- `example.com` and `first.example.com` route to first server.
- `second.example.com` and `third.example.com` route to second server.

2 server connect to 2 different database.

The sessions are stored in database.

If I change SESSION_DOMAIN in .env to `.example.com` and login to first server from `example.com`, the session is reused in `first.example.com`, too. However, I can't login to second server `second.example.com`, it seems to also reused session from first server.

How do I reuse session for some specific subdomain only? I'm using PHP with laravel.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to reuse session between different web sites ? Maybe Single-Sign-On would be better approach like OAUTH2

Comment: @Osta I thought it makes things a little more complicated because we can already share session between domain and subdomain. Thus, I didn't use SSO, but SSO is good answer for this.